# Creating IAM policy to list and access single bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have created the following IAM policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This works in that the only bucket they can access is the correct one, but what I want to do is set it so that the only bucket that shows when going to the bucket list is the one they have access to.

I tried changing the ARN in the listallmybuckets action to the ARN of the bucket itself, but this just gives a "no access" error when going to the bucket list

How do I change this to only list the bucket they have access to in the bucket list?

Answer (score 2):

S3 buckets are owned by a specific **canonical user ID** that is tied to an AWS
account. When a principal is given `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` in an IAM policy, they
have access to enumerate all buckets owned by the **canonical user ID** that 
provides their credential's `arn` (the account number that is the fifth segment
in the `arn` of the user or role bearing the permission).

This means that for a given account, all principals either have
`ListAllMyBuckets` for all buckets in the account or none at all.

With **AWS Organizations**, it's relatively easy to create a dedicated account and
then provide credentials (or cross account access) to a bucket (or set of buckets)
that are isolated from all others; this may simulate the limited listing behavior
the OP is asking for.